# Radio Buttons not appearing as they should

Tags: javascript, html

I had to edit existing HTML (change title and variables) and run it through Firebug. My radio buttons are boxes (or not showing at all) and I don't know why. I've attached a screenshot of both the HTML code and the Firebug output. I used an online converter to convert the HTML to JavaScript. I am new to JavaScript and am having a hard time getting a handle on this. Any help would be appreciated!

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Radio Buttons</TITLE>
<META content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dwindows-1252" =
http-equiv=3DContent-Type>
<SCRIPT type=3Dtext/javascript>
    function pick_a_business_card(){
        var base_cost =3D get_business_card_value();
        alert(base_cost);
    }
    function get_business_card_value(){
        var radio_buttons =3D document.getElementsByName('business card');

        for (var i =3D 0, length =3D radio_buttons.length; i < length; i++) {
        =09
            if (radio_buttons[i].checked) {
                return radio_buttons[i].value;
            }
        }
    }
</SCRIPT>

<META name=3DGENERATOR content=3D"MSHTML 8.00.7601.18129"></HEAD>
<BODY>
    <FORM id=3Dbusiness_card_addons_calculation_form method=3Dpost action=3D#>
    <H2>Radio Buttons</H2>
    <P><STRONG>Pick a Business Card:</STRONG><BR><BR><INPUT id=3Dvertical value=3Dvertical
=
type=3Dradio=20
name=3Dcolor> <LABEL for=3Dvertical>Vertical</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=3Dhorizontal =
value=3Dhorizontal=20
type=3Dradio name=3Dcolor> <LABEL for=3Dhorizontal>Horizontal</LABEL> <BR><INPUT =
id=3DFoldover=20
value=3Dfoldover type=3Dradio name=3Dcolor> <LABEL for=3DFoldover>Foldover</LABEL> =
</P>
    <P><INPUT onclick=3Dpick_a_business_card() value=3D" Submit " =
type=3Dbutton></P>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/ w3 schools is great starting place for tutorials for new languages. I wouldn't recommend on line converters, as first of all you don't know if they're 'right' and second you'll not learn what the javascript is doing!

Comment: 3Dradio is not a valid input type. Why does 3D prefix all your HTML attributes?

Comment: %3D is equal sign (=)

Comment: One cannot convert HTML to JavaScript. That doesn't even make sense. Please explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please include a minimal example that reproduces the problem, a clear problem statement, and any error messages or other information to help identify the problem. Without this information, it is hard to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears some things were encoded improperly in your conversion.

I cleaned up your code a bit [here](http://jsbin.com/kibuvitu/2/edit?html,js,output) which should help get you started

Here is the full HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function pick_a_business_card(){ 
      var base_cost = get_business_card_value(); 
      alert(base_cost);

    }
    function get_business_card_value(){
      var radio_buttons = document.getElementsByName('color');

      for (var i = 0, length = radio_buttons.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radio_buttons[i].checked) {
          return radio_buttons[i].value;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<FORM id=business_card_addons_calculation_form method=post action=#>
<H2>Radio Buttons</H2>
<P><STRONG>Pick a Business Card:</STRONG><BR><BR><INPUT id=vertical value=vertical
type=radio
name=color> <LABEL for=vertical>Vertical</LABEL> <BR><INPUT id=horizontal
value=horizontal
type=radio name=color> <LABEL for=horizontal>Horizontal</LABEL> <BR><INPUT 
id=Foldover
value=foldover type=radio name=color> <LABEL for=Foldover>Foldover</LABEL>
</P>
<P><INPUT onclick=pick_a_business_card() value=" Submit "
type=button></P></FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, I'd recommend putting quotes around your HTML attributes.

Comment: I was given HTML pages and had to modify the text and variables to something other than what was there. I didn't touch any of the code other than what I wanted to change. I guess I don't know enough to know what else should have changed as well. I only have until tonight to fix it. Ugh. I get an error when I run what you provided in Firebug. You said "Help get you started", I am guessing this implies I have to do something more to it to get it to work right? LOL.

Comment: There is a lot of invalid HTML in the code you provided. Namely the "3D" and the "=20" that appears all over the place. I removed most of those, but missed some in the javascript. I updated the link and the example works now. Also, your JS was searching for items named "business card" but your inputs were named "color"--I fixed that too and the example is working now.

Comment: Ah, I thought I found all the 'color' inputs! I thought the 3D had to do with the styling of the radio buttons. Silly me. :)

Comment: I still can't get it to run in Firebug, any idea why? Sorry I am so needy. LOL

Comment: It's running fine for me. Firebug 2.0.2 in Firefox 30.0. Perhaps add the missing quotation marks around your HTML attributes.